how to explain variable latency on a ping?
When I ping to my router, I have the result below which I find rather important for a Wi-Fi network:
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=79.5 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=103 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=3.66 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=45.0 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=3.79 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=89.7 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=5.34 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=8 ttl=64 time=134 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=9 ttl=64 time=3.45 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=10 ttl=64 time=77.8 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=11 ttl=64 time=63.6 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=12 ttl=64 time=85.9 ms

--- 192.168.1.1 ping statistics ---
12 packets transmitted, 12 received, 0% packet loss, time 11015ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 3.454/57.873/134.014/43.063 ms

I tried using an Ethernet cable and my ping is less than 1 ms. I also did the same test on another network with the same result. All tests were done on a fresh installation of Ubuntu 22.4.
Additional information :
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14e8
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14e9
00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14ea
00:01.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14ed
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14ea
00:02.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14ee
00:02.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14ee
00:02.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14ee
00:03.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14ea
00:04.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14ea
00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14ea
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14eb
00:08.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14eb
00:08.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14eb
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 71)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14f0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14f1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14f2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14f3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14f4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14f5
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14f6
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14f7
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation AD107M [GeForce RTX 4060 Max-Q / Mobile] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 22be (rev a1)
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8852CE PCIe 802.11ax Wireless Network Controller (rev 01)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8211/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 16)
04:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Sandisk Corp WD Blue SN580 NVMe SSD (DRAM-less) (rev 01)
05:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Phoenix1 (rev c2)
05:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Rembrandt Radeon High Definition Audio Controller
05:00.2 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 19h (Model 74h) CCP/PSP 3.0 Device
05:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15b9
05:00.4 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15ba
05:00.5 Multimedia controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] ACP/ACP3X/ACP6x Audio Coprocessor (rev 63)
05:00.6 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h/19h HD Audio Controller
06:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14ec
06:00.1 Signal processing controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] AMD IPU Device
07:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14ec
07:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15c0
07:00.4 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15c1

$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 6.8.0-38-generic (buildd@lcy02-amd64-049) (x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-13 (Ubuntu 13.2.0-23ubuntu4) 13.2.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.42) #38-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Jun  7 15:25:01 UTC 2024


There are so many things that may cause a few extra ms from one ping to the next it is impossible to list them all. Any source of electrical or magnet interference can cause a few ms of delay. You have zero packet loss so I do not see why you have an issue with this.

I don't think about interference, since the test on another site has the same problem. Unless it's a computer design problem. I'm wondering about a driver problem, but I don't see anything on the web.
